# Is there a way to input variable values from outside to terraform main file?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way I can input variable values from outside to terraform main file. It can be a excel sheet or sql db. Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I want to pass values to terraform main file variables from a web page. Like I will take the input to create resources on web page and pass those inputs to main file as values. Is there a way I can achieve this ? Or if possible can I pass values from excel sheet to main file ?

Comment: If you're writing code to do this why not just turn that input into a tfvars file?

Comment: Because those values will change according to requirement. That is why I want to take it as input. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes but if you have some service that people can input stuff into and that generates a CSV and then you orchestrate pointing Terraform at that why are you bothering to generate a CSV and not a tfvars file?

Comment: Ok I got what you are saying. Suppose I have a web page taking all inputs. Then how do we populate these values into tfvars file ?

Comment: Basically that is where I am stuck, and that is why I created this thread. I know I can input values to terraform using tfvars files, where I can put all constant values. But if values keeps changing based on my requirement. Then how can I make sure everytime tfvars file is getting updated with those values.

Answer (score 0):

What you can't currently do is point you cmdline at a db i.e. to replace a tfvars file, but what you can set up in Terraform is to use a number of different key value stores:

## consul

https://www.terraform.io/intro/examples/consul.html

## aws parameter store (using a resource or data)

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html

There are quite a number of other key/value stores to choose from but there's no zero code solution and you will end up with lots of these statements:

## Setup a key in Consul to provide inputs

```
data "consul_keys" "input" {
  key {
    name    = "size"
    path    = "tf_test/size"
    default = "m1.small"
  }
}
```

Comment: I am looking to take inputs from people on a web page. And pass those inputs as values to main file variables. Is it possible ? Or is it possible to use excel file instead to store the values and pass it in main file ?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that;

1. You can use a tfvars file with all your inputs and you can use one file customer, user, environment
2. You can pass the variables to terraform executable on the command line
3. You can define environment files prefixed wit TF_VAR_[variable]
4. You can use https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ssm_parameter.html as suggested above
5. You can even store variables in DynamoDB or any other database
6. You can use Consult+Vault as well

Comment: And also suppose I have a web page and I am putting all the values there. Then I want to use those values inside tfvars file, then how do we reference those values from tfvars file ?

Comment: @KundanKumar https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html, https://learn.hashicorp.com/terraform/getting-started/variables.html#from-environment-variables,